# Configuring SMTP Mailer Wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, email

I'm trying to configure a Wordpress plugin called SMTP Mailer. I've tried with both my Gmail credentials and Yahoo credentials (and associated SMTP Host name, of course). For Gmail, I turned on "Access for less secure apps" last night, and waited in case the change needed time to take effect. Still no luck.

Am I configuring something wrong? Is Google not cooperating with it? Do I need to use a different plugin?

If I need a different plugin, the only thing that's really important is that it's free AND doesn't rely on anything else that's paid-for (i.e., Postman is "free" but relies on Mandrill, which is not)

my SMTP Host is smtp.gmail.com (or Smtp.mail.yahoo.com)

using SMTP Authentication

using TLS with port 587

I have tried both matching and different email addresses in From Email Addresses

When I try to send a test email via the plugin, I get this. (Gmail credentials)

```
Connection: opening to smtp.gmail.com:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
Connection: opened
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO neptunechiropractic.com
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO neptunechiropractic.com
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [69.65.3.206]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
Auth method requested: UNKNOWN
Auth methods available on the server: LOGIN,PLAIN,XOAUTH2,PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN,OAUTHBEARER,XOAUTH
Auth method selected: LOGIN
CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
CLIENT -> SERVER: ZG9udXRndXlAZ21haWwuY29t
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
CLIENT -> SERVER: V2lsbGlzOTc=
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 then try again."
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again."
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Learn more at"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at"
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsl534-5.7.14 LzEE2lLLfImAv_yM_TVulSQukCMK2TP2e2zHMoLfHinmHQd_xySluckyAX79IsvIkFa3Lq534-5.7.14 s6uWFgvPxxU-PiR37bZZltNOtAHRdVATLM-qA3o11Y0BE-C8n1zsYATIen43jCTQhMmHce534-5.7.14 C3Jd_XLqoxkjKGaIzK8RN0nz30-EM-JItSaPRsn6dS8PQoW7-AGIHQlE8Yw4EnMcHxus_6534-5.7.14 lVtcod88LXd49PvBGTZj-32bgg57U> Please log in via your web browser and534-5.7.14 then try again.534-5.7.14 Learn more at534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp"
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection q77sm1720219itb.22 - gsmtp
Connection: closed
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

**EDIT:**

I've now received 4 successful test emails from the WP Mail SMTP plugin, and 1 from the Easy WP SMTP plugin. This is still a problem though, since I can't seem to get it to happen again to save my life. There are only so many settings in either plugin, and most of them are either known to me (email address and password) or are a choice between 2 or 3 options, like TLS/SSL and their associated port.

I typically get an indication that either the test email failed to send, or "could not authenticate" despite not having changed my credentials. Today, I've been getting mostly internal server errors, with the only exception being using Easy WP, with TLS (and port 587), which still gives the failure message mentioned above. WP Mail with TLS, or SSL on either, and everything else I've tried today, results in an internal server error.

Easy WP error message - SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***UPDATE***
After a day at this we figured it out! GoDaddy were blocking SMTP requests. I recommend he used the free version of SendGrid and used the SendGrid plugin which uses the SendGrid web API and now it all works!

Yay :)

---

Plugin seems broken to me.

Consider using this one which can use gmail so OAuth 
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gmail-smtp/

Or if you prefer SMTP I recommend WP Mail SMTP
https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/faq/

Gmail SMTP settings are:

smtp.gmail.com
Port 465 with SSL
OR
Port 587 with TLS

Username and password should be your normal gmail details.

Comment: I have been trying the second one, and got it to send 4 emails, though it took a while and I can't get it to do it again, since I don't know which set of settings were successful. Even so, it's more promising than the alternatives I see (namely, as I was doing before, lol)

Comment: @donutguy640 see my update. Also, if this has helped and worked be sure to upvote it and mark it as correct :-) thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I know the TLS and SSL ports. I'll mark it as an answer when I get it to cooperate again. Currently tinkering but can only get one of two outcomes on sending a test email, "loading" for half an hour, then server error, or "The result was:bool(false)" followed by a crapton of debugging output

Comment: well, I figured out it only loads for half an hour and such, if I'm not using SSL. *shrugs* Now I see it's telling me it can't authenticate, despite not having changed the credentials since last night. Same result with Yahoo credentials and SMTP host. AAUUGH! Any ideas?

Comment: Weird @donutguy640 you'd need to use SSL. The other option is to use the port 25 option which is aspmx.l.google.com it doesn't require authentication but mail can only be sent to gmail or google apps users. Are you able to connect via SMTP through an email client?

Comment: not sure if you meant authentication or encryption for port 25, but yeah, I just configured Thunderbird to check my Gmail, works fine.

Comment: @donutguy640 both. Can you send from thunderbird?

Comment: yes I can. I tried no authentication/encryption with aspmx.l.google.com, no luck. Another thing though, think this counts as extended discussion? It's suggesting we move it to chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126869/discussion-between-shiv-and-donutguy640).

Comment: well, to any reading this, despite having received test emails from two plugins, I still can't replicate a successful test email in either one. I also don't know what settings led to success, since I don't receive them till much later. I can't understand how or why, since there are only so many settings to mess with, most of them either known, like my email address, or selecting from a small set of choices, like TLS/SSL and associated port

Comment: Try the oAuth plugin. It's guaranteed to work but requires a bit more setup (5 mins work) @donutguy640 that's also a secure way which means you can turn off less secure sign ins ;)

Comment: What's the full name of the plugin? I'm seeing Sudo Oauth, WP-OAuth, WP OAuth Server...

Comment: @donutguy640 the one I linked in my post. https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/gmail-smtp/

Comment: I've gone back to chat again, since this is still just back and forth between the two of us.

Comment: So apparently, GoDaddy is demonspawn (according to me, mind you) and is the reason I wasn't able to send squat. Using SendGrid fixed it, and I can now send emails.